# Getting returned value from another javascript file using async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

```
class monitor {
    constructor(){
        this.delay = config.delay

    delay(time) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(resolve, time);
        });
    }
        async redacted (pid) {
            if (this.err === true) {
                await this.delay(this.delay)
            }
            console.log("MONITOR > Getting Item Attrs")
            const options = {
                method: 'get', 
                url: url + pid + '.json', 
                headers: {
                    accept: '*/*',
                    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                },
                proxy: this.proxy
            }

            return req(options)
            .then((res) => {
                //console.log(res)
                let variants = res.data.skus
                //console.log(variants)
                const att = []
                for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(variants)) {
                    if(value.inStock) att.push(key)
                }
                if(att.length >= 1){
                    console("MONITOR > Sourced Item")
                    return att;
                } else {
                    ("MONITOR > No Variants Available")
                    this.oos = true
                    this.redacted(config.pid);
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (err?.response?.status == 403) {
                    console.error("MONITOR > Proxy Block @ GET PRODUCT")
                    this.err = true
                    this.redacted(config.pid);
                }
            })
            
        }
}
var hello = new monitor().redacted(config.pid);
console.log(hello)
```

From what I understand I need to wait for the promise to finish before returning but I am confused on how to execute this with my code and also call this file and store the return value in another file. I'm not sure if my formatting is wrong as well, but I tried changing and no fix anyways

Comment: Try using this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call There are a lot of helpful soloution there.

Comment: `store the return value in another file` - Don't expect to be able to return the value from an async function to non-async code, it doesn't work like that.  Your var hello will not contain anything useful when the console.log(hello) line runs.  You would need to await redacted (only can do that from within async code) or provide a then function to run after redacted.

Comment: @james My other script is using async code as well but It is using multiple threads within the same class based on my config parameters so I wanted to implement a single "Task" in this case a monitor to push variants to an array to be used within another class x amount of times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This snippet isn't using asynch but, it gives you the idea. You need to `await` or `.then` the promise (the fetch/request). You first fetch the remote JSON file then you parse it / read it. Something like:

```
    function getJSON(url) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('get', url, true);
            //xhr.responseType = 'json';
            xhr.onload = function () {
                var status = xhr.status;
                if (status == 200) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response)); // <---------------
                } else {
                    reject(status);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        });
    };

    getJSON(primaryURL).then(function (res) {
        if (res) {
            //do something
        } else {
            console.log("response not found");
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

Comment: Presumably the `req` function already does that.

Comment: Right, well he must be forgetting to parse the file?

Comment: The question is very unclear. I think it might be yet-another "How can I get the resolved value of a promise instead of the promise?" question, but it lacks the usual "This is what I tried, this is the result I expected, this is the result I got" that would make it clear.

Comment: @Quentin Okay so essentially I have another script that has another class running "tasks" x amount of times (Task count) but I need a singular function call (Task) for this so I am trying to figure out the easiest way to implement it which might just be calling it once outside of my taskcount loop.

Comment: Steve in that case, `task(){tasks()};` right? Or, if `tasks` is async then await resolve prior to moving on.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston Yes await for the response which I am doing but I seem to be getting undefined now... I can post my entire app script so someone can help if possible in a new question

Comment: you need to inspect what you're getting back. if you're in a browser log it to console and use dev tools crtl+shft + i to see what it is.